# Accepting proposals for chat rooms

Tags: discussion, tags, chat, specific-question

I very much would like to avoid this problem: [Avoiding making so many new chatrooms called "Discussion between user[A] and user [B]" which later become frozen or not very useful](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/353643/391772)

We have a couple of inactive *and* un-named chat rooms that can be given a name and more useful purpose:

- https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113915/discussion-between-saismaran-s-b-pes1201701189pes-and-ruslan
- https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117114/discussion-on-question-by-jw-are-there-examples-of-ab-initio-predictions-on-sma

I very much like the chat rooms we currently have for various Matter Modeling software:

- [LAMMPS](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109805/lammps) (180 messages)
- [GAUSSIAN](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110569/gaussian) (108 messages)
- [PHONOPY](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112358/phonopy) (67 messages)
- [ASE](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111469/ase) (57 messages)
- [VASP](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109983/vasp) (45 messages)
- [Q-CHEM](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109797/q-chem) (32 messages)
- [GPAW](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112878/gpaw) (21 messages)
- [MOLPRO](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112274/molpro) (19 messages)

We also have rooms that feed us special questions or information:

- [Bounty Land!](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109905/bounty-land)
- [HNQ Land!](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109935/hot-network-questions-)
- [SE Network Land!](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110113/whats-going-on-elsewhere)
- [Milestone Land!](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109902/milestones)

Then we have rooms for discussing the site:

- [General chat room for Matter Modeling Meta](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113019/general-chat-room-for-matter-modeling-meta)
- [General chat room for Matter Modeling Main](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107323/modeling-matters)
- [Ask a moderator](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110431/ask-a-moderator)
- [Tags](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107328/tags)
- [Testing Feeds](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108277/testing-feeds) (discussion about any bugs/anomalies in how the feeds are working)

Then we have 1 subject-specific room which doesn't fit into any of the above categories, but is for talking about [physical-properties-of-materials](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/physical-properties-of-materials):

- https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110288/physical-properties-of-materials

#### Questions now come up:

**To what should we re-name the first two rooms mentioned here?**

- Maybe a room for graphics?
- Maybe another room for a Matter Modeling software:

  - [vesta](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vesta) is a software with more questions on our site than [phonopy](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phonopy).
  - [gromacs](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gromacs), [cp2k](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cp2k), and [orca](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/orca) have more questions on our site than [gpaw](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gpaw). Maybe [orca](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/orca) and NWChem can be incorporated into the MOLPRO chat room so that it becomes the "MOLPRO, NWChem, ORCA (MNO)" room?
  - [pyscf](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pyscf) has more questions on our site than [molpro](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/molpro) (which at 8 questions is still not insignificant).
- Maybe another subject-specific tag such as:

  - [density-functional-theory](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/density-functional-theory) (our most popular tag by far!)
  - [software](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software) (our 2nd most popular tag! and could be combined with [software-assistance](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-assistance) and [software-recommendations](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-recommendations))
  - [molecular-dynamics](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/molecular-dynamics) (our 4th most popular tag!) The LAMMPS room covers this topic a bit already.
  - [high-performance-computing](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/high-performance-computing) (our 13th most popular tag!)

**Maybe the PHONOPY room could be changed to be inclusive of other python software?**

- [thermo-calc](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/thermo-calc), [pyscf](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pyscf) and others may be included in this category (for example), though [python](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python) itself might be better suited in a separate (subject-specific) room (there is already [this very active room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python) on SO for that though).

**Maybe the GPAW room could be changed to be a "subject-specific" room covering related topics?**

- [pseudopotentials](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pseudopotentials), [plane-waves](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plane-waves), and [projector-augmented-wave](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/projector-augmented-wave) come to mind for this.

#### In which room should these conversations go?

- A 5-message back-and-forth has occurred here: [Is it right to neglect very small imaginary frequencies?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/3942/5)
- A 5-message back-and-forth has occurred here: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/3836/5 (maybe we could have an [nwchem](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nwchem) software room? or NWChem chat can be combined with the [molpro](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/molpro) software room?)
- A 7-message back-and-forth has occurred here (luckily I messaged in between, so the prompt to create a room "spuriously" may have been prevented): [Is there a more efficient hard sphere packing algorithm?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/3899/5)
- A 7-message back-and-forth has occurred here (though it was before the question was migrated to us from Chem.SE): [Interpret 2D and 3D data from a PubChem summary of organometallic molecule? Can I "flatten" it when showing on a surface?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/3926/5)
- A 5-message back-and-forth (this time involving me!) has occurred here (and I'd really love to continue the conversation since I'm learning so much from a true expert in the field!): https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/3920/5
- A 7-message (at least!) back-and-forth has occured here: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/3508/5
- A 5-message back-and-forth has occurred here and is not over: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/3879/5 (perhaps a room for [protein-folding](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/protein-folding), [biomaterials](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/biomaterials), [proteins](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proteins), and [docking](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/docking) could be made?)
- A 5-message back-and-forth has occurred here and is not over: [Energy cut-off value for conformer calculations](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/3912/5) (again this would go in the room for [protein-folding](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/protein-folding), [biomaterials](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/biomaterials), [proteins](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proteins), and [docking](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/docking))
- A 5-message back-and-forth has occurred here: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/3939/5 (again this would go in the room for [protein-folding](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/protein-folding), [biomaterials](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/biomaterials), [proteins](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proteins), and [docking](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/docking))
- A 6-message back-and-forth has occurred here (involving me!): https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/2307/5 - ***I am reluctant to answer the user's last comment because I fear that a new room will be created*** (this *might* fit into a [high-performance-computing](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/high-performance-computing) room).
- A 5-message back-and-forth has occurred here: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/685/5 (it might fit into a [high-performance-computing](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/high-performance-computing) room).
- A 6-message back-and-forth (involving me! but luckily interrupted by others in between): https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/1111/5 (it would be a perfect fit for a [high-performance-computing](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/high-performance-computing) room).
- A 5-message and 4-message back-and-forth has occurred here: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/2051/5 (this would be a good fit for a [high-performance-computing](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/high-performance-computing) room, but probably would be even better in the existing room for [vasp](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vasp))
- An 8-message back-and-forth occurred here (involving me!) but luckily it was interrupted once: [Which schedulers are compatible with a virtual machine?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/1570/5) (this could fit in a room for [high-performance-computing](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/high-performance-computing))
- A lot of back-and-forth happened here, but luckily was interrupted sufficiently: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/1356/5 (this would be a perfect fit in a room for [high-performance-computing](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/high-performance-computing))
- A 5-message back-and-forth happened here (involving me!) but luckily was interrupted: [Is there a set of updated, comprehensive benchmarks for speed comparison between different quantum chemistry packages?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/1354/5) (this would be a good fir in a room for [high-performance-computing](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/high-performance-computing))
- An 8-message *and* 6-message back-and-forth happened here (both involving me!): [Which Linux distribution is best for Matter Modeling?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/1224/5) (this would be a good fir in a room for [high-performance-computing](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/high-performance-computing))
- A lot of back-and-forth happened here, but luckily was interrupted sufficiently: [Materials Modeling with Raspberry Pi?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/1125/5)  (this would be a good fir in a room for [high-performance-computing](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/high-performance-computing))
- Although this one was interrupted, I had deliberately not responded because the discussion was getting too long in the comments: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/3725/5  (this would be a good fir in a room for [high-performance-computing](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/high-performance-computing))
- A lengthy discussion occurred here (it was recommended to write in the Spectroscopy & Potentiology chat room): [Is it right to neglect very small imaginary frequencies?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/3942/5)
- 5 comment back-and-forth about QTAIM: [Interpreting electron localization function (ELF) results](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/1721/5)
- 4 comment back-and-forth on an NWChem question, *I added a comment to attempt avoiding a possible spurious room creation*:
  [Energy per unit cell in NWChem differs for different supercells despite the same k-points density](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/4314/5)
- 6 comment back-and-forth on a question about mathematics of quantum chemistry: [How can I implement the Cartesian harmonics?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/4453/5)
- [Example of a standard/archetypal/simple 4-band un-gapped condensed matter model with analytic results?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/4673/5)

Comment: I will add a link where [all rooms associated with the site](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&sort=active&host=mattermodeling.stackexchange.com) can be displayed.